# Error while binding JNDI name com.jinsoft.dating.server.ProfileEJBRemote

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

Does anyone know why I'm getting the following error when I attempt to deploy my EAR to Glassfish:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name ...
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException
```

I am using Maven, so my file structure (simplified) looks like this:

```
ear
  pom.xml

ejb
+--src
  +--main
    +--java
      +--(package)
        Profile.java
        ProfileEJB.java
        ProfileEJBRemote.java
  pom.xml

web
+--src
  +--main
    +--java
      +--(package)
        ProfileController.java
    +--webapp
      +--META-INF
        index.jsp
        listProfiles.xhtml
        newProfile.xhtml
  pom.xml
```

EAR pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
<artifactId>dating</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>dating</name>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>ejb</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>war</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>

        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
                <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>dating.war</bundleFileName>
                <contextRoot>/dating</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
                <artifactId>server</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>dating.jar</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
        </modules>
        <displayName>JinDate</displayName>
        <!-- If I want maven to generate the application.xml, set this to true -->
        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>            
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

EJB POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>server</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WAR POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>web</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jinsoft.dating</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

First guess? You have another deployment on the server which also has an EJB with the name you try to deploy. Maybe, this is an old test deployment? 
This basically means, you are trying to deploy a new object to the JNDI tree under a name that is already used by another object. Get rid of all older delployments, clean your project and try again.

Rgds,
M

Comment: It is the only application being deployed to the Glassfish container.